# Does anyone know the HTML entity used by Flickr as arrows in the action menu?

Tags: html, css

If you open an image in FLickr (http://www.flickr.com/photos/visualpanic/233508614/) and click on the **Actions** menu button, you could see a pop-up menu with arrow icon on top of it. It is not a image but it's combination of two characters (◢◣).

Does anyone know what's the entity value for those characters? Googling was not much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

◢ ◣ (written as &#9698; and &#9699;)

Note: I pretty much copy pasted the UTF-8 codes from your post :)

Comment: i tried view->Source (in the hope that I can get the value) but still the characters were shown as it is. :(

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a short script from the characters in Java... A little cheating ;-)